# Google Sheets using AVERAGEIF with specific cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get the average of percentages in every other cell, excluding those cells with a 0.  I tried this formula.

=AVERAGEIF(C2,E2,G2,I2,K2,M2,O2,Q2,S2,U2,W2,Y2,AA2,AC2,AE2,AG2,AI2,AK2,AM2,AO2,"<>0")

I get this error. "Wrong number of arguments to AVERAGEIF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 21 arguments."

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

AVERAGEIF has the following syntax:

> AVERAGEIF(criteria_range, criterion, [average_range])

Arguments are in parentheses, separated by commas.
An optional argument is enclosed in square brackets.
Therefore, you get the message: "Expected between 2 and 3 arguments".

Try:

```
=AVERAGEIF({C2,E2,G2,I2,K2,M2,O2,Q2,S2,U2,W2,Y2,AA2,AC2,AE2,AG2,AI2,AK2,AM2,AO2},"<>0")
```

- **[AVERAGEIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529?hl=en)**